# Error in point in polygon analysis using shapely

Tags: python, geo, shapely

In my python script I have successfully imported a geojson using the `shapely` package and converted to multipolygon with

```
test = geojson.load(open('test.geojson'))
multi = [shape(x['geometry']) for x in test['features']]
polygon = MultiPolygon(multi)
print(polygon)
```

This returns the multipolygon:

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((-122.4187874794006 37.77566736187935, -122.4132943153381 37.77999215545677,..
```

And I successfully created points from sample data:

```
for item in items:
  coords = Point(item['current_position']['coordinates'])
  print(coords)
```

which returns:

```
{"coordinates": [-122.39883, 37.74576166666667], "type": "Point"}
{"coordinates": [-122.39868166666666, 37.74570333333333], "type": "Point"}
{"coordinates": [-122.39873666666666, 37.74593], "type": "Point"}...
```

However, when I run a point in poly analysis, I am returned an error:

```
for item in items:
  coords = Point(item['current_position']['coordinates'])
  polygon.contains(coords)
```

returns...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SF_scraper.py", line 44, in <module>
    polygon.contains(coords)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/base.py", line 634, in contains
    return bool(self.impl['contains'](self, other))
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/predicates.py", line 13, in __call__
    self._validate(other, stop_prepared=True)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/topology.py", line 17, in _validate
    if ob is None or ob._geom is None:
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geojson/base.py", line 42, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: _geom
```

What could be going wrong here? I have followed the documentation precisely

Comment: Have you tested this on your MultiPolygon? From the documentation: "Rings of a valid Polygon may not cross each other, but may touch at a single point only. Again, Shapely will not prevent the creation of invalid features, but exceptions will be raised when they are operated on."

Comment: Check if you imported "Point" from shapely and not from geojson.